# querying foreign keys

Tags: android, sql, database, foreign-keys

So I have found many tutorials on how to set up android for a foreign key. I am pretty sure I am not doing that wrong. the problem I am having is not being able to pull it into the list view that I want. Can some one show me how to query this information right so that I can see it inside of the listview?

Comment: I assume you want to see the value of the stuff in the other table instead of the foreign key itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM alpha a, beta b WHERE a.beta_id=b.id
```

That'll give you all the columns from both tables where the reference holds.

Comment: Right I got that much the problem is how do I view it in the list activity?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with database queries, then.  Look at a [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html)  I'm down voting your question since the information you actually want has nothing to do with what you actually asked.